# Execute SQL on CSV files on IPython Notebook

Tags: sql, csv, ipython

I have imported testdata.csv file onto datascientistworkbench, and i was trying to excute sql statement on this csv file by writing codes on Ipython notebook. I did find the following .py and had it installed into Ipython notebook, but to be honest i dont know what to do next. 
Here is what I have installed so far:

```
           !pip install querycsv
```

Based on the description of using this querycsv.py from this [link](https://pythonhosted.org/querycsv/), the next step i should be doing in the normal python environment/software is this:

```
           querycsv.py -i testdata.csv "select distinct IPID from testdata;"
```

But i guess i cannot just simply copy and paste the above code into IPython notebook. Any advice? Many thanks!

Comment: I recommend reading the file in as a CSV, inserting data into SQLite database, then querying database

Comment: @openwonk thx! but i dont know how to do it, is it possible to "inserting data into SQLite database" by writing codes in IPython notebook?

Comment: @openwonk     i mean after I have read the file as CSV, i am just wondering how to "insert data into SQLite database", i have been googling about it but i got confused. thx for ur help!

Comment: That `querycsv.py` command is meant to be run at the command line, not in Python code. You can run command line commands in IPython with the `!` prefix, but then you don't get structured data to use elsewhere in the code.

Comment: Not familiar with that package, but I'm sure that it works as intended.  I would trust @Thomas K suggestions.  If you want to write it in raw Python, use the [csv](https://pymotw.com/2/csv/) package to load and parse data, then use the [sqlite3](https://pymotw.com/2/sqlite3/) package to load into a database.

Comment: FYI, you can also use the CLI interface of `sqlite3` to import the data directly.  First, set `.mode csv`, then `.headers on`, then `.import path/to/data.csv`

Comment: [Here](http://hosseinkaz.blogspot.com/2014/11/importing-csv-file-into-sqlite3-python.html) is a quick tutorial in raw Python... Good luck!

Comment: DuckDB is a much better alternative than SQLite: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74908223/709975